# Remmina asks for credentials before opening

Tags: remmina

Why does Remmina always ask for credentials before opening? It clearly doesn't need them, because I can just cancel the prompt and it works normally. I don't want to open the login keyring at startup because other people use this computer and I also don't want to have to cancel an unnecessary prompt every time I use Remmina. I'm testing on a new installation of ubuntu 20.04 LTS and using Remmina v1.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this by reinstalling Ubuntu,

Comment: I came looking for a solution. I leave thinking about nuclear annihilation.